Angular implementing websocket using sockJs and Stomp getting CORS Error
I used Stomp and SockJS for implementing WebSocket, and our backend is built with Spring Boot.
this is my client code:

and baseApi is something like this:
 baseApi: 'https://api.test.com'

this is what I get in the network tab:

and when I click on this error I receive a 200 status code. that is weird:

for more detail:
When I open my project with Chrome CORS safe mode, everything works fine
also when I open "https://api.test.com" separately, it works without CORS
additionally, my backend developer set allowed-origin for this address
I also put our backend configuration codes:
application.yml:
spring:
  config:
    name: staging
  cloud:
    gateway:
      globalcors:
        cors-configurations:
          '[/**]':
            allow-credentials: false
            allowed-origins:
              - 'https://api.test.com'
            max-age: 3600
            allowed-headers: '*'
            allowed-methods:
              - POST
              - GET
              - PUT
              - OPTIONS
              - DELETE

WebSocketConfig.kt:
@Configuration
@EnableWebSocketMessageBroker
class WebSocketConfig(
    @Value("\${app.white-labels-list}")
    private val whiteLabelList: Array<String>
) : WebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer {
    override fun configureMessageBroker(config: MessageBrokerRegistry) {
        config.enableSimpleBroker("/topic")
        config.setApplicationDestinationPrefixes("/app")
    }

    override fun registerStompEndpoints(registry: StompEndpointRegistry) {
        registry.addEndpoint("/websocket-endpoint")
            .setAllowedOrigins(*whiteLabelList)
            .withSockJS()
    }
}


could you share the backend code snippet ? make sure CORS is enabled

The network tab image doesn't give so much details. Can you show the column for the request method? Also make a bigger screenshot.

I put backend codes

in this case

Access-Control-Allow-Origin

It seems set twice, put this part of the code to the backend side.
spring:
cloud:
    gateway:
      default-filters:
        - DedupeResponseHeader=Access-Control-Allow-Origin Access-Control-Allow-Credentials, RETAIN_UNIQUE

